# How to add methods the source code using ASTRewrite?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I was looking for some sample example code that could help me write full-fledged code for adding a method in another class using ASTRewrite.

P.S: It is not a problem of adding lines in a method that is already created. Instead, I wish to create a new method which doesn't exist in user's class and which has the capability of accepting parameters and has some code inside it.

Answer (score 0):

If, generally, you are able to make changes using `ASTRewrite` then probably all you need is to obtain a `ListRewrite` for the body declarations of the declaring class, s.t. like:

```
astRewrite.getListRewrite(type, type.getBodyDeclarationsProperty())
```

the resulting `ListRewrite` has various `insertX` methods to suite your needs.

The method can be *created* beforehand using the factory methods from `AST` (i.e., for this you don't need to bother the rewriter for this).